# \cite command adds a "p." whenever there's a number in the optional argument

Tags: biblatex, citing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref,backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite[first state]{author_book}
    \cite[11]{author_book}
    \cite[p. 11]{author_book}
    \cite[1.12]{author_book}
    \cite[prop 1.12]{author_book}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output :

> [Aut22, first state] [Aut22, p. 11] [Aut22, p. 11] [Aut22, p. 1.12] [Aut22, prop 1.12]
>
> References
>
> [Aut22] Some Author. Book’s title. The City: Publisher, 2022.

When the \cite[...]{} command finds a number, it automatically assume it is a page number and ads a "p." to the output citation.
But it's a theorem/proposition label ! Actually when I used a page in my file I added a "p." myself.

Was running using biblatex (style = alpha) before and it wasn't doing it, but now I have to use biber.
Any idea how I can force the file to NEVER produce a "p." or something ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the pagination field to this work, the value none will suppress the p, see 2.3.12 Pagination in the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2022},
pagination={none}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite[first state]{author_book}
    \cite[11]{author_book}
    \cite[p. 11]{author_book}
    \cite[1.12]{author_book}
    \cite[prop 1.12]{author_book}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As also mentioned in the documentation you can completely disable the biblatex handling of page numbers by adding to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
```

Comment: But some works do have pagination. And I'm even using some. 
Also, if I don't want to edit all my \cite inputs, I have 4 pages of bibliography, so quite a lot to edit... 
I'm more looking into a change of some parameter in the header..?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, my change only affect this one work and I didn't change any cite command. But I think you should really read the documentation (2.3.12 and 3.15.3) and then try to clean up your input and your bibliography.

Comment: What I mean is that outside my example, in my work, there are 4 pages of bibliography that you want me to change.
Also, in these, there are some references where I used the pagination because I had to write from which page to which of some book the article is in, and because of broken online bibliography I really had to. So I can't change pagination in the .bib file.

I want a command which is in the .tex header.

Which documentation are you talking about ? Google gives me 45 different ones... But I'd be happy to read the part you pointed out ;)

Comment: Use `texdoc biblatex` on the command line to find the biblatex documentation. Or use https://texdoc.org/index.html

Comment: I'm more looking for a command which says "hey, computer, in this file, whenever you read a \cite command with an optional argument, please don't try to add a "p." because it is never a page ref and when it is, the "p." is already in the text of the optional argument"

Comment: thanks for the link.

Comment: I added an edit how to completly disable the automatic pagination.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out this in the documentation. Thanks, it is what I was looking for :)